# Granting ManageBuildResources permission to a TFS user

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

so this is the issue:

I have a TFS 2012 installed on a server A and I want to install a TFS Build Service on server B. The TFS on server A has a DefaultCollection which I want to link it to a Team Build. When I try to configure the build server it shows a failure message: User1 needs "ManageBuildResources" permission set to allowed. User1 is NOT in any group, its a single lonely user, then I ask a coworker about the permissions. Now in the security settings of Team Explorer it shows that User1 has "ManageBuildResources" set to allowed on DefaultCollection. Still, when I try to configure it, it shows again the same failure message.

So I read in the Microsoft website that User1 must be in Project Collection Administrators group in order to configure a build server, do I need to make User1 a member of this group, even if User1 has all the privileges? Because I don't understand why it shows that User1 doesn't have privileges.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you currently need to make a user part of Project Collection Administrators in order to be able to add a build server to your collection.